# How can a contact lens on the eye's cornea produce a resolved image at the retina?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, vision

I'm going to take Wired.com's [The Display of the Future Might Be in Your Contact Lens](https://www.wired.com/story/mojo-vision-smart-contact-lens/) at face value and assume that the concept is legitimate (see also [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/technology-51137379/smart-contact-lens-it-feels-seriously-sci-fi) and additional technical details in [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/news/a-single-contact-lens-could-give-your-entire-life-a-head-up-display/)).

Optically, the cornea where the device sits is the first surface of the eye's lens, and where the transition from air to solid takes place. It's impossible for the retina to image a normal spatial pattern generated on the surface of the cornea.

Instead, what's <s>seen by</s> imaged at the retina is going to be *roughly* the Fourier transform of the wavefront at the cornea.

So how can this concept possibly work optically?

Comment: The retina does not "view", the retina acts as the screen. A contact lens just changes the refracting strength of the cornea a bit.

Comment: @Pieter further reading on the processing that takes place within the several layers of neurons within the retina will show that it 1) does not in fact function as a "screen" and 2) does much more than one. Its a pretty darn amazing processor in fact. However, to avoid further pedantry I'll change "seen by" to "imaged at".

Comment: Ah, now I understand the question. I suppose the display that is built inte the contact lens generates a laser ray that writes on the retina with some moving mirror, or (less likely) that it emits many rays.

Comment: @Pieter I'd thought "laser" as well, with some clever wavefront manipulation, but the CNET article mentions micro-LED arrays.

Comment: if the input is placed against the lens then, aside from a quadratic phase factor that can be removed, at the back focal plane (here the retina) you get the Fourier Transform of the input distribution, see for a very clear derivation in Goodman "Introduction to Fourier Optics", chapter 5, p103. So set the source input to be the inverse Fourier transform of what you wish to see at the BFP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very specific question, and deserves a specific answer. The OP rightly imagines that an image source at the surface of the eye can't be focused by the eye.

When you are curious about a technology, you can often find an online copy of the relevant patent application or issued patent.  In this case, US 2020/0020308, which you can find through the [U.S. Patent Office](http://www.uspto.gov) by searching for patent applications by Deering, the inventor. In there, after sifting through a lot of irrelevancies, you can find this image:  [Thick contact lens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MKU6.jpg).

It's not a thin contact lens; and it appears that it depends on folding and a set of tiny lenses to move a virtual image of the image source out to a few meters or more.  I am pretty sure there will be huge barriers to making this thin and light enough to actually be a wearable contact lens.  They *don't* have a working prototype with a contact lens form.

Answer (score 1):

Tiny emitters allow for very small optical systems.

For example:

> Somehow the image must be pushed away from the cornea. One way to do that is to employ an array of even smaller lenses placed on the surface of the contact lens. Arrays of such microlenses have been used in the past to focus lasers and, in photolithography, to draw patterns of light on a photoresist. On a contact lens, each pixel or small group of pixels would be assigned to a microlens placed between the eye and the pixels. Spacing a pixel and a microlens 360 micrometers apart would be enough to push back the virtual image and let the eye focus on it easily. To the wearer, the image would seem to hang in space about half a meter away, depending on the microlens.

(From IEEE [Spectrum](https://spectrum.ieee.org/biomedical/bionics/augmented-reality-in-a-contact-lens) 2009; there’s lots of more recent work but I didn’t see as pedagogical  a quote)

Comment: It's hard to choose which of multiple good answers to accept, thanks for your help!